# How to select column from many-to-many table by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')),
    db.Column('created_at', db.DateTime())

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False, unique=True)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

I want to get User's roles with 'created_at' column in many-to-many table.

Expectedd result:

```
[
    {user_id:1, role:'user', created_at:dateTime},
    {user_id:1, role:'admin', created_at:dateTime}
]
```

Comment: Use an association model: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object